# Constrain fk relationship so it can only have one of a type

Tags: django, django-models

I have Booking and Payment models. Each Booking can have more than one Payment.  There are more types and fields but this should be enough to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    cost = models.IntegerField(...)

class Payment(models.Model):
    TYPE_THIRD_PARTY 'thirdparty'
    TYPE_STRIPE = 'stripe'
    TYPES = [
        (TYPE_THIRD_PARTY, 'Third party payment'),
        (TYPE_STRIPE, 'Stripe online payment')
    ]

    booking = models.ForeignKey('Booking')
    payment_type = models.CharField(..., choices=Payment.TYPES)
    amount = # ...
```

Our system accepts third party Bookings and automatically creates TYPE_THIRD_PARTY Payments for accounting. If the amount on a third party Booking changes, we just bump the amount in the existing payment.

We have had some issues with admins creating additional TYPE_THIRD_PARTY payments. This breaks things when the automated updates come through.

I know I can dummy the forms to remove the third party payment choice, but is there a sensible way I can constrain Payment at database level so that there can only be one with payment_type=TYPE_THIRD_PARTY per Booking?

Other Payment types are okay not being unique.

Comment: Can you show the fields that define the relationship between Booking and Payment?

Comment: If only the `thirdparty` type should be unique you need to enforce it in `pre_save` signal.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Whoops. Added.

Comment: @RadosławGanczarek As I understand it, pre_save won't always fire (eg bulk_create, update). It also relies on querying every save. I've no idea if in-DB unique checking is faster, but I fee like it should be. A partial-index (in Postgres) type of thing.

Comment: Alternative would be to create a separate model for third party costs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enforce this with a [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#unique-together) constraint:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('booking', 'payment_type'),)
```

Comment: This will mean that I can only have one of each type. I only want one value of Payment.payment_type to be unique. I'm looking for the mythical `unique_together_where`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. There's no way to constrain that at the db level; it's a job for model or form validation.